# Parallel tests in JUnit 4 with maven-surefire-plugin 2.19 don't work

Tags: java, junit, maven-3, junit4, maven-surefire-plugin

As the title says I've got a Maven 3.5 project using `maven-surefire-plugin` 2.19 and JUnit 4.12. I'm trying to parallelize test execution but no luck.
I've tried so far the following configurations (with different threads/processes count):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${surefire.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefile-reports</reportsDirectory>
        <forkCount>1C</forkCount> <!-- also 3-5 and etc -->
        <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${surefire.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefile-reports</reportsDirectory>
        <parallel>classes</parallel>
        <threadsCount>4</threadsCount>
         <!-- Also unlimited threads and etc -->
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I'm running tests with the following command on Jenkins in Jenkins multibranch pipelines:

```
act("Tests", stagesInfo) {
    try {
        sh "./mvnw test -Pcoverage"
    } finally {
        pipelineUtils.archiveTestResult()
    }
}
```

Tests run for the same time (or more) they did before attempting to parallize them or they simple hang on. `SpringRunner` I'm using extends `ParentRunner` (according to [the spec](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html) it is must have).

Please, share any ideas, I don't have a clue on how to make it work. Thank you very much!

Comment: How many cores and how much memory does your jenkins server have?

Comment: @ilooner seems like 1 cpu core only and almost 8gb of memory

Comment: If you only have 1 core available then parallelizing the tests won't make them run faster since all the threads will be competing to run on the same core. You need to get a machine or VM with multiple cores so that threads can run on different cores simultaneously.

Comment: @ilooner ok, I will try on my local machine and get back, thanks!

Comment: @ilooner well, seems like it was me that stupid. you were right, go ahead and answer the question if you'd like to:) thank you, you're awesome! how could our Jenkins machines be such a trash..